# Infinite gas estimate for empty contract

Tags: web3js, solc

I am trying to deploy a contract with web3, and always get an error `Error: exceeds block gas limit`, even for correct or empty contract code.

Actually, gasEstimates always throws :
`Error: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction`

Even for an empty contract, the gas estimate is infinite :

`var compiledContract = solc.compile("pragma solidity 0.4.17; contract Contract { }");
var abi = compiledContract.contracts[':Contract'].interface;
var abiArray = JSON.parse(abi);
var bytecode = compiledContract.contracts[':Contract'].bytecode;
var gasEstimate=web3.eth.estimateGas({from : web3.eth.coinbase, data : web3.toHex(bytecode)});` throws "exceeds allowance".

Please do you know where I can be wrong ?

Thank you,
Pierre.

Answer (score 1):

In fact I did two errors, here there are in case it can help someone:

1. To the data field passed to estimateGas must be `data : '0x'+bytecode` and not `data : web3.toHex(bytecode)`.
2. When deploying the contract I had put too much gas, check the current block gasLimit field.